# Pass props to react routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, react-router

I have a snackbar handler in Main that I want to pass down to each Route component as a prop. How can I achieve this ?

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
  <Main history={browserHistory}>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/comp1" component={comp1} />
      <Route path="/comp2" component={comp2} />
      <Route path="/comp3" component={comp3} />
      <Route path="/comp4" component={comp4} />
    </Switch>
  </Main>
</Router>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass down props, including bound event handlers, like this in React Router:

```
<Route exact path={'/:userId/create-project/:projectId'}  component={() => {
      return (
        <ProjectEditor
          goToDashboard={this.goToDashboard}
          nextProject={this.state.nextProject}
          goToProject={this.goToProject}   
          updateUserProject={api.updateUserProject}              
        />
      )
   }} 
/>
```

Comment: I would suggest to use HOC since the solution here may repeat for many components that will share same logic (snackbar handler)

Answer (score 0):

You can place your component inside Route and pass here any props.

```
<Route path="/comp1"><Comp1 myHandler={MyHAndler}/></Route>
```

`Comp1` get all props from `Route` too.